# Redirect in apache2 (httpd) in CentOS7 old route to new

Tags: apache, centos7

I try redirect the old path to new:

http://mydomain.edu.co/handle/123456789/*
 to
http://mydomain.edu.co/handle/22.333.4444/*

where * are any number of ID

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/handle/123456789/
RewriteRule ^handle\/(.*)\/(.*) handle/20.333.12345/$2 [L,R=301]
```

But don't work, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Since you used the 301 redirect from the beginning (you should not until you are sure it works correctly), your browser probably cached your previous (probably invalid) redirects. Clear your browser cache, test redirects using `curl -I …` not with your browser.

Comment: Hi emix, I use links but it's same error, don't charge if I try the old url